# Finding an odd number from int[] array using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I created  an array and trying to use streams for finding the first odd number as follows:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12};
int oddOne = Stream.of(arr).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).findFirst().get();
                                   // fails above
```

> `Error: |  incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int`

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-):

```
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

Which:

> Returns a sequential `IntStream` with the specified array as its source.

As of now you are using the overloaded method [`Stream.of(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) which simply:

> Returns a sequential `Stream` containing a single element.

So it will only be a `Stream` of the single `int[]`

---

Also as nullpointer noted, calling `get()` without ensuring there is in fact an odd number in the `Array` will cause an error. It is best to use `orElse()` to return a default value if no odd number is present

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to access `int[]` and not `int`eger inside your `filter`. One way to resolve that would be to use `IntStream` with the help of [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)) as:

```
int oddOrMin = Stream.of(arr) // Stream<int[]> and not integers
                     .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream) // IntStream
                     .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                     .findFirst() // OptionalInt
                     .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE); //default to some value
```

Comment: better start with `Arrays.stream(arr)` directly, no reason to create a `Stream<int[]>` (with one single element) to then create an `IntStream`

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can also use `IntStream` to stream `int[]`

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12};
int result = IntStream.of(arr).filter(i->i%2 !=0).findFirst().getAsInt();
System.out.println(result); //9
```

If you don't have any odd numbers then `public int getAsInt()` throws `NoSuchElementException.`

> If a value is present in this OptionalInt, returns the value, otherwise throws NoSuchElementException.

So as `@nullpointer` suggestion always recommended to use `orElse(int other)`

> public int orElse(int other)

Answer (score 1):

Varargs are tricky. The signature of `Stream.of()` is `Stream.of(T ...arg)`.
Where T can be any class. But you are passing an array of native `int` which does not work. Instead it thinks the whole array is one object. 
Problem arises when you use an array of native types.
Your code gives a stream of just one element of type `int[]`.
You could rather use :

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12};
```

You can simply use this or use `Arrays.stream(arr)` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EvenNumberSum {

    public static int sumEvenNumbers(int[] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                     .filter(num -> num % 2 == 0)
                     .sum();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int result = sumEvenNumbers(numbers);
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers: " + result);
    }
//This can be used to sum odd numbers
public class EvenNumberSum {

    public static int sumEvenNumbers(int[] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                     .filter(num -> num % 2 != 0)
                     .sum();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int result = sumEvenNumbers(numbers);
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers: " + result);
    }
//This can be used to sum even numbers
```

Comment: How does that answer the question "*finding the first odd number*"?