# Finding an odd number from 2 dimensional integer array using Stream

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying the code as follows

```
int[][] mat = new int[][]{new int[]{2,4,6}, new int[]{8,9,12}};
int oddInAll = Arrays.stream(mat).filter(i -> i%2 != 0).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

But this gives me the error

> |  Error: |  bad operand types for binary operator '%' |    first
>   type:  int[] |    second type: int |          int oddInAll =
>   Arrays.stream(mat).filter(i -> i%2 != 0).findFirst().getAsInt(); |
>   ^---^
>
> |  Error: |  cannot find symbol |    symbol:   method getAsInt() |
>   int oddInAll = Arrays.stream(mat).filter(i -> i%2 !=
>   0).findFirst().getAsInt(); |
>   ^-------------------------------------------------------------^

What did I miss this time?

Answer (score 10):

Well, `Arrays.Stream` in this case would result in your `i` to be of type `int[]` which can not be used in `filter`.

I would suggest using a similar example I'd shared previously for this operation as well.

```
int oddOrMin = Stream.of(arr) // Stream<int[]> and not integers
                     .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream) // IntStream
                     .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                     .findFirst() // OptionalInt
                     .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE); //default to some value
```

#### Similarity

The syntax of iterating over the one-dimensional and two-dimensional array remains same in the above solution.

#### Difference

The solution [that I'd shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909024/1746118) for one-dimensional array makes use of [`Stream.of(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T)) where *T is `int[]`* as provided in the input. On the other hand, the solution suggested for two-dimensional array makes use of the [`Stream.of(T... values)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) where again the `int[][]` is considered to be `int[]...` and hence *T evaluates to `int[]`* to finally create a `Stream<int[]>`.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [flatMapToInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) instead :

```
int oddInAll = Arrays.stream(mat).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                     .filter(i -> (i % 2 != 0)).findFirst().getAsInt();
```